# Is there a way to tell a text (csv) file has been converted or processed using wrong encoding?

Tags: csv, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

*Sorry the title is a bit vague, I could not come up with anything better. I'll edit it as soon as a better title crosses my mind.*

The **problem** is as follows:

1. **My system exports a CSV file in `UTF-8`**
2. **User opens the file in his editor - maybe as UTF, maybe as some other charset - say, `Windows-1250`** (but can be **any** charset, really)
3. **User saves the file in `UTF-8`** *<- the problem* *
4. **User imports the file back to the system,** and now all the accents and special chars had turned gibberish.

**Edit**: The encoding problem may or may not occur! Also, I don't know which charset may have been 'used' for the unwanted conversion.

And the **question** is:

**Is there a way to tell whether in any one step of the process the encoding was improperly interpreted or altered?**

I don't need anything else, just to warn the user that the utd-8 charset was at one step of the proces misinterpreted or the file has been otherwise damaged due to character set conversion..

Also, I don't need any hacker-proof solution, I only  want to *lessen the burden imposed*  on the users so that they be warned when bringing about a potentially disastrous situation.

---

**Details:**

I'm dealing with CSVs here and I don't see any easy way to *hide* a control character so that the user won't delete it incidentally or on purpose.

The editors used are of various kind, mainly MS Excel in German language but unfortunately it's not limited to this one. There is the possibility to export a Unicode (UTF-16 LE) text-file, but it doesn't solve the problem in question - that the uploaded file had its Unicode malformed because of (unintentional) character set manipulation.

The solution I've come up with is that I'll always have the first line saying something like `® Company Inc. - Do not remove this line`, with the (R) sign being the control character - it's easy to check it it is the expected character or it isn't.  But I'm sure you'll agree that it's way too far from a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the encoding they used (in this case CP1250, although German Excel would rather indicate CP1252) you can just try to undo the changes and see whether valid UTF-8 comes out, that is:

1. Read the file as UTF-8
2. Convert to CP1250
3. Interpret the bytes as UTF-8 again

if step 3 has errors, then the file apparently was UTF-8 to begin with (at least with a negligible probability of error), if not then what you described happened.

As an added bonus: This will mangle nothing if the data was in ASCII.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> $s = '® Company Inc. - Do not remove this line'
PS Home:\> $bytesInFile = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($s)
PS Home:\> $wrongText = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250).GetString($bytesInFile)
PS Home:\> $wrongText
Â® Company Inc. - Do not remove this line
PS Home:\> $wrongBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($wrongText)

PS Home:\> # 1. read as UTF-8
PS Home:\> $readString = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getString($wrongBytes)
PS Home:\> # 2. Convert to CP1250
PS Home:\> $readStringAs1250Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes($readString)
PS Home:\> # 3. Interpret as UTF8 again
PS Home:\> $interpretedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getString($readStringAs1250Bytes)
PS Home:\> $interpretedText
® Company Inc. - Do not remove this line
```

If the file wasn't mangled:

```
PS Home:\> # 1. read as UTF-8
PS Home:\> $readString = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getString($bytesInFile)
PS Home:\> # 2. Convert to CP1250
PS Home:\> $readStringAs1250Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes($readString)
PS Home:\> # 3. Interpret as UTF8 again
PS Home:\> $interpretedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getString($readStringAs1250Bytes)
PS Home:\> $interpretedText
� Company Inc. - Do not remove this line
PS Home:\> $interpretedText.Contains([char]0xFFFD)
True
```

The safest way might be to tell the encoding/decoder to throw errors on invalid characters, but that depends a bit on what exactly you're using. Usually you can set that, though (I'm just not well-versed in that part of .NET to do so from PowerShell). Checking for U+FFFD Replacement Character would be the next best option.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! Looks like I need to edit my question - it is not sure that the conversion to CP1250 took place at all or whether the codepage _used_ for the malencoding was indeed CP1250 od some else. And all I need is the detection, I don't really want to bother the server with any corrections, it's up to the user.

Comment: +1 I've edited the question now to better emphasise what I need. Your suggestion with the BOM and checking for conversion errors seems viable, if there comes no better solution!

Comment: I did not mention the BOM at all. It's just that interpreting text that already is UTF-8 in an 8-bit codepage and then as UTF-8 again will very, very likely garble non-ASCII characters – but in a predictable way (either the decoder throws an error or inserts U+FFFD). So if the file encoding was *not* tampered with, that little conversion dance above will *yield errors*. If it was, then you get something mostly sensible back. But even if you don't know the encoding that might be improperly used, you can still detect the error, but not correct it automatically.

Comment: Yes, I get it now (I misread the FFFD for the BOM, sorry). That is conceptually what I've come with, I really like the possibility of converting it back. But if at all possible, I'd like to avoid the first line at all, if at all possible. I could not come up with nything more sensible than this, so if in a few days time nothing better comes along, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you very much!